# How to Show/Hide multiple column fields based on dropdown selection - SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, javascript, jquery, list-form

I am using a SharePoint list in which we are using multiple columns covering different process steps to be filled based on a dropdown selection.

The steps are different depending on the mission selection. I want to be able to show/hide fields column depending on the dropdown selection of the mission.

I have added a code here as an example to showcase what I need to do based on the following:

The mission selection column is called 'Selection' and includes dropdown options: 'Yellow', 'Orange', 'Red', 'Green'.

I worked the code on the following columns: 'Country', 'Animal', 'Fruit', and 'Colour'. However, the code is not working at all. I don't have experience in coding so obviously something is not working out but I am not able to detect the issue, so highly appreciate your support to provide any leads on this.

```
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery-3.3.1.js"> </script>
<script src="/SiteAssets/sputility.js"> </script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    //Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection
    $("select[title='Selection']").change(function () {
      var ddlValue = SPUtility.GetSPField('Selection').GetValue();
      if (ddlValue == 'Yellow') {
        SPUtility.ShowSPField('Country');
        SPUtility.ShowSPField('Colour');
        SPUtility.HideSPField('Animal');
        SPUtility.HideSPField('Fruit');
      }

      if (ddlValue == 'Orange') {
        SPUtility.ShowSPField('Fruit');
        SPUtility.ShowSPField('Colour');
        SPUtility.HideSPField('Country');
        SPUtility.HideSPField('Animal');
      }
      if (ddlValue == 'Red') {
        SPUtility.ShowSPField('Animal');
        SPUtility.HideSPField('Country');
        SPUtility.HideSPField('Fruit');
        SPUtility.HideSPField('Colour');
      }

      if (ddlValue == 'Green') {
        SPUtility.ShowSPField('Colour');
        SPUtility.ShowSPField('Animal');
        SPUtility.HideSPField('Country');
        SPUtility.HideSPField('Fruit');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser's console? jQuery and SPUtility files loaded properly on page?

Comment: Can you please ensure the jQuery and SPutlility CDN files are loaded(Update the CDN files path if any issues)

Comment: @GaneshSanap, thanks for the reply. I have uploaded them under SiteAssets. Do I need to reference the full site URL( i.e http...)?

Comment: @KarthikeyanGanesan, thank you for the reply,  I've uploaded them under SiteAssets but I might be missing something between uploading them on SiteAssets and linking them with my List. Have I missed any step? you mentionned if files loaded properly on page, how can I verify that?

Comment: if your site url is like: `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Mysite/siteassets/...` then try referencing file like: `/sites/Mysite/siteassets/jquery-3.3.1.js`. if that doesn't work then try adding complete file URL. You can ensure the files are loaded or not under **Sources** tab in browser's developer tools. Also, if file is not loaded you will get 404 error in browser's console.

Comment: @GaneshSanap, so I checked in the browser's developer tools and console and it is showing as following despite having uploaded them under SiteAssets: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at sputility.js:2046
sputility.min.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at sputility.min.js:10
NewForm.aspx?[...] Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: @GaneshSanap, I just tried few things and it worked :) Thanks very much for your support!

Comment: Great, I am glad it worked for you. I have written it as an answer below. Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you and it will help others with same question to find the correct answer easily.

Comment: Will do; just as a note for future reference and to complete this thread, I also added ')}' at the end of this script as the end of input was incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good to me. I thinks there is some issue with the jQuery and SPUtility files you referenced in your code.

Make sure jQuery and SPUtility files are loaded properly on NewForm.aspx page?

If your file URL is like: `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Mysite/siteassets/jquery-3.3.1.js` then try referencing file like: `/sites/Mysite/siteassets/jquery-3.3.1.js`.

If that doesn't work for you then try adding complete file URL.

You can ensure the files are loaded or not under Sources tab in browser's developer tools. Also, if file is not loaded you will get 404 error in browser's console.

Also make sure that you are not loading jQuery files multiple times on the same page else it will conflict with the different versions.